# Dependencies not getting installed when I run "pulumi new azure-python". It just keeps builiding the wheel

Tags: azure, pulumi, infrastructure-as-code, pulumi-azure, pulumi-python

I am trying to install the dependencies of azure-python using pulumi and the dependencies are not getting installed. It just keeps building the wheel with no output whatsoever.

I run the following commands:
$ mkdir azure-python; cd azure-python;
$ pulumi new azure-python

[Here is what happens when I run the commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZT2b.png)

But if I try running the commands to install aws-python, all the dependencies gets installed and I can deploy using pulumi up

[The output if I run aws-python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ppCb.png)
I should be getting something like this for azure-python too

Can anyone please help me?

Edit: It errored out after a long time.
Here is the error:
Failed to build pulumi-azure-native
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pulumi-azure-native, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
error: installing dependencies failed; rerun manually to try again, then run `pulumi up` to perform an initial deployment: installing dependencies via 'C:\Users\shara\OneDrive\Desktop\new\quickstart\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install -r requirements.txt': exit status 1

[Here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkQLa.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it can't create a file it needs to build the Azure wheel, namely

```
error: could not create 'build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\pulumi_azure_native\m365securityandcompliance\v20210325preview\getprivate_link_services_for_o365_management_activity_api.py': No such file or directory
```

This looks like a permission problem. A quick glance at the pulumi [docs](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/clouds/azure/get-started/begin/) indicates that it should be installed using

```
choco install pulumi
```

So I would check that that has been done correctly.

One other thing that strikes me is that you are using a relatively old version of pulumi - v20210325 (or 2.23.2). The current version is 2023-05-19 (or 3.68). Both Azure and Pulumi have evolved over the last two years, so it may just be that you need to upgrade Pulumi to get proper Azure support.

PS: For future reference - please include errors as text, rather than screenshots. It makes it a lot easier to look up the error message and refer to it in the answer.